# using column name as foreign key in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

Is there a way to reference "column-names of given table" as foreign key in sqlite?

I've tested:

```
create table "test"(
    test TEXT
);
create table "othertest"(
    othertest TEXT references PRAGMA table_info("test")[1]
);
```

But as expected, it does not work... (the error is `Error: near "table_info": syntax error`, but even if table_info was accepted, I doubt that the `[1]` part would be valid)

Comment: What would it be for? You can't have query that would use column specified by expression anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the "What would it be for?", please see my response below

Answer (score 0):

In general, SQL database management systems don't allow expressions in DDL. Systems that support information_schema views won't let you use a scalar subquery to return the target for a foreign key reference. This is a syntax error in all the SQL dbms I use day to day.

```
create table test (
    article_id integer primary key 
        references articles (select column_name 
                             from information_schema.columns
                             where table_name = 'articles'
                             and is_nullable = 'NO')
);
```

What is the real problem you need to solve by trying to do this?

Comment: In fact, I've a data model where I need a table that can describe a mapping to generate views. I don't know if this is clear... It could be seen as a table that stores aliases for columns, and that will be used later to generate views using this mapping

Comment: @CircleCode: You can do that by using SQL to read the table, and using application code to generate literal DDL for the views. But you can't use non-constant expressions within the DDL.